# How to use a for loop to always change the string to another string and to another in an array anytime an if condition is true

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a Java program in which I have an array list of 5 strings and a countdown timer of 5 seconds. My question is this, I want the string to be changing anytime the timer is in 1 second. That is whenever the countdown timer is at 1 second, the string should change to another string then when it gets to 1 second it should change to another string till all the strings in the array list as shown.

Comment: Hey Thompson, Do you have to use single timer?

Comment: Yes, just one timer

Comment: can you provide some code that shows what you have tried already?

Comment: What do you mean when you say every time the timer is in 1 second. If the timer starts at 5 seconds then it will on be in 1 second only once until the timer finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the timer somewhere, and use:

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
```

I think this demo code will help you:

```
class Helper extends TimerTask 
{ 
    public static Timer timer;
    public static int i = 0;
    public static void setTimer(Timer timer) {
        Helper.timer = timer;
    }
    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Timer ran " + ++i); 
        if (i==5) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }
    } 
} 

public class Test3
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        Timer timer = new Timer(); 
        Helper task = new Helper();
        Helper.setTimer(timer);
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the arraylist  please read the question again, I need the strings to change when the timer is in 1seconds

Comment: Please help me create  an array list of any 4 strings, then make the string always change when timer is at 1 seconds

Comment: I think you should do some effort.

Comment: @Thompson SO is to help programmers solve there issues, not to provide complete assignment solution for them.